# How can I get a notification when build workspace is finished?

Tags: eclipse

How can I write a plugin or program routine that gets notified when "build workspace" finishes in Eclipse?

Is [IProgressMonitor](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FIProgressMonitor.html) useful for this?  If so, how do I get ahold of it?

Comment: May I know why you need this and is it okay if notified in console like `sysout`?

Comment: I guess you can write a `Ant` build.xml which will `echo` the text which will get printed on console.

Comment: I need it because Eclipse used to block launching my application server until build workspace was done, and now it does not.  I feed notifications from a lot of applications into Growl, and I would like to get a notification from build workspace that I could pipe into Growl as well as pipe into a wrapper that would wait on launching my server until build workspace is done.

Comment: Console wouldn't work - I am looking for an API that can monitor events like begin/end build workspace so that I can program reactions to those events.

Comment: On the `Run/Debug` Preference Page, there is a setting to wait to launch until any ongoing Builds are completed. Is it not set properly?

Comment: @nitind, I have "Wait for ongoing build to complete before launching" set to "Always" on Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching.  But ever since I upgraded to Luna it doesn't seem to have an effect for my application server, which no longer seems to be launchable from the run/debug configurations - only the server tab.

Comment: I'm running Luna, I see my Tomcat configurations through `Run` > `Debug Configurations...`, and I can launch from there.  Under the `Common` tab, I see a checkbox by `Launch in background`.  Perhaps that will help?

Answer (score 4):

You can wait for the automatic build to finish using:

```java
Platform.getJobManager().join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_AUTO_BUILD, null);
```

This will block until the builds have finished (and do nothing if the build is not running).

You would probably also want to wait on the manual builds are well:

```java
Platform.getJobManager().join(ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_MANUAL_BUILD, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to receive a **notification** (rather than blocking), try this:

```java
IWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener(myListener, IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD);
```

The Javadoc of [IResourceChangeEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceChangeEvent.html) gives more details on usage and on information found in the event instance.

Comment: Thanks, man.  Both your answer and greg-449's are worthy of receiving the bounty reward here, so I've started a second bounty.  Looks like Stack Overflow won't let me award it for 24 more hours, though, so stand by.